# Connection to SQL Server 2008 through .NET

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server 2008 on my machine which is (Windows XP SP3).

Also I have Visual Studio 2008 installed in another machine on which there is a .net application. Now while I am trying to connect to the SQL Server from my .NET application.

I am unable to do so. I get an error message :

> The client was unable to establish a
>   connection because of an error during
>   connection initialization process
>   before login. Possible causes include
>   the following:  the client tried to
>   connect to an unsupported version of
>   SQL Server; the server was too busy to
>   accept new connections; or there was a
>   resource limitation (insufficient
>   memory or maximum allowed connections)
>   on the server. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on
>   the other end of the pipe.)

Is it because of the client version being 2005 (which gets installed by default with Visual Studio 2008) and SQL Server being 2008?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.

Do you actually have named pipes enabled for your SQL Server?

Comment: Can you please help me how enable Named Pipes. I enable the "SQL Server Browser" on the machine on which SQL Server 2008 is installed. That error is gone. Bout now I am getting the Named Pipes error.

Comment: Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager. http://www.pinaldave.com/download/SQL_EnableTCPIP.gif

Comment: Steps: 1) Enable the SQL Server Browser 2) Enable the Named Pipe. Restart the server and this seemed to work for me. Cheers!!!